# Setting System.Uri from android uri string xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin, imageview, uri, imagesource

I have a camerapage which takes a picture, resizes it to a thumbnail and saves this resized image to a file locally on the android phone. I then try to send this uri-string to a viewmodel which is supposed to set its ImageSource property from this uri. I am currently unable to load the image from the url.

Here is my code:

In CameraPage(inside Take photo method)

```
var documentsPath = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);

            using (var imageStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                await image.CompressAsync(Bitmap.CompressFormat.Jpeg, 40, imageStream);
                image.Recycle();
                imageBytes = imageStream.ToArray();
                var thumbnail =await DependencyService.Get<IPicResizer>().GetResizedImage(imageBytes);

                // Temporary file to store the downloaded image
                Java.IO.File tmpFile = new Java.IO.File(documentsPath + "/"+fileName + ".jpg");
                tmpFile.ParentFile.Mkdirs();
               // String path = MediaStore.Images.Media.InsertImage(this.Context.ContentResolver, documentsPath, fileName, ""); //(this.Context.ContentResolver, image, imgName.ToString(), null);
                uri = Android.Net.Uri.Parse(tmpFile.Path);
                // The FileOutputStream to the temporary file
                var fOutStream = new FileOutputStream(tmpFile);              

                try
                {
                    fOutStream.Write(thumbnail, 0, thumbnail.Length);

                    fOutStream.Flush();

                    fOutStream.Close();
                    DialogService.HideLoading();
                    DialogService.ShowSuccess("Saved picture at: " + uri.ToString());

                }
                catch (Java.IO.FileNotFoundException ex)
                {
                    DialogService.ShowError(ex.InnerException.Message);
                }
                catch (Java.IO.IOException ex)
                {
                    DialogService.ShowError(ex.InnerException.Message);
                }

                camera.StartPreview();
                await App.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PushModalAsync(new InfoPage(imageBytes, tmpFile.AbsolutePath), false);
            }
```

InfoPages view model:

```
 ImageSource Source {get;set;}
   public InfoViewModel(byte[] image, string imageUri)
        {

            if (image != null)
            {
                _image = image;
                imageurl = new Uri("file:///" + imageUri, UriKind.Absolute);                
                Source = ImageSource.FromUri(imageurl);

            }
      }
```

All help is appreciated :)

Comment: Did you confirm that your file exists after writing it with the stream ? If I remember correctly you had to use the MediaStore or it would not work.